# Estimate of Coefficient Variance in multiple regression

Tags: estimation, variance, nonlinear-regression

I'm trying to compute an estimate for the variance of the estimated coefficients
in a non-linear regression using the formula described in  [link](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Fox-Companion/appendix-nonlinear-regression.pdf).
I can't figure out how to build $F_{ij}$

Let's consider for simplicity a quadratic regression:

$f = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x + \beta_2 x^2$

and let's say we have computed the estimate $\hat{\beta}_0, \hat{\beta}_1, \hat{\beta}_2$ from a set of $m$ observations.

To me $$ F = \frac{\partial f(x_i)}{\partial \beta_j} = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & x_1 & x_1^2 \\
\vdots & \vdots &\vdots \\
1 & x_m & x_m^2 \end{array} \right) $$

But of course it can't be cause it does not depend on $\hat{\beta}$ anymore...

Comment: This is not a non-linear regression. "Linearity" and non-linearity refer to how thw estimated unknown parameters enter the equation, not to whether there appear regressors that are non-linear transformations of other regressors. Set $x^2 \equiv z$ and re-write the equation. The estimator variance is the usual linear-regression one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Matrix $F$ is actually correct and one can use it to build the covariance matrix of the regression coefficients:
$$D(\hat{\beta}) = \sigma^2(F^T F)^{-1}$$
Now denoting with $d_{jj}$ the $j-th$ diagonal element of $D(\hat{\beta})$ we
can specify the distribution of $\hat{\beta}_j$ as
$$ \hat{\beta}_j \sim N(\beta_j, \sigma^2 d_{jj}) $$
where $\sigma^2$ can be estimated using the sum of squares of the residuals:
$$ \hat{\sigma}^2 = \frac{1}{m - n} \sum_{i=1}^m \left( y_i - \hat{y}_i\right)$$

Comment: The normality result depends on assuming that the error term follows a normal distribution. This is not necessary for the derivation of the variance of the estimator.